# Find lowest and highest values split into rows from a single string of concatenated values

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, ssis, etl

This is a follow-up to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952949/create-n-new-rows-from-raw-data-such-as-1000-1000n): in which I got an excellent answer for that question provided by *uzi*. I however noticed that a new Company, `Company3` also used single data Points, such as account 6000 which does not follow the manner of the previous companies which makes uzi's recursive cte not applicable.

As such I feel like it is required to alter the question, but I Believe that this complication would issue a new question rather than an edit on my previous one due to having a great impact of the solution.

I need  to read data from an Excel workbook, where data is stored in this manner:

```
Company       Accounts
Company1      (#3000...#3999)
Company2      (#4000..#4019)+(#4021..#4024)
Company3      (#5000..#5001)+#6000+(#6005..#6010)
```

I believe that due to some companies, such as `Company3` having single values of accounts such as `#6000` that I need to, in this step, create a result set of the following appearence:

```
Company       FirstAcc LastAcc
Company1      3000     3999
Company2      4000     4019
Company2      4021     4024
Company3      5000     5001
Company3      6000     NULL
Company3      6005     6010
```

I will then use this table and JOIN it with a table of only integers to get the appearance of the final table such as the one in my linked question.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: is the problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good t-sql splitter function makes this quite simple; I suggest [delimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/). This will perform significantly better than a recursive CTE too. First the sample data:

```
-- your sample data
if object_id('tempdb..#yourtable') is not null drop table #yourtable;
create table #yourtable (company varchar(100), accounts varchar(8000));
insert #yourtable values ('Company1','(#3000...#3999)'),
('Company2','(#4000..#4019)+(#4021..#4024)'),('Company3','(#5000..#5001)+#6000+(#6005..#6010)');
```

and the solution:

```
select 
  company, 
  firstAcc = max(case when split2.item not like '%)' then clean.Item end),
  lastAcc  = max(case when split2.item     like '%)' then clean.Item end)
from #yourtable t
cross apply dbo.delimitedSplit8K(accounts, '+') split1
cross apply dbo.delimitedSplit8K(split1.Item, '.') split2
cross apply (values (replace(replace(split2.Item,')',''),'(',''))) clean(item)
where split2.item > ''
group by split1.Item, company;
```

Results:

```
company   firstAcc   lastAcc
--------- ---------- --------------
Company1  #3000      #3999
Company2  #4000      #4019
Company2  #4021      #4024
Company3  #6000      NULL
Company3  #5000      #5001
Company3  #6005      #6010
```

Answer (score 1):

*I made a little editing to @uzi solution from the other question, in which i added three other CTE's and used windows function like `LEAD()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` to solve the problem. I don't know if there is a simpler solution, but i think this is working good.*

```
with cte as (
select 
    company, replace(replace(replace(accounts,'(',''),')',''),'+','')+'#' accounts 
from 
    (values ('company 1','#3000..#3999'),('company 2','(#4000..#4019)+(#4021..#4024)'),('company 3','(#5000..#5001)+#6000+(#6005..#6010)')) data(company, accounts)
)
, rcte as (
    select 
        company, stuff(accounts, ind1, ind2 - ind1, '') acc, substring(accounts, ind1 + 1, ind2 - ind1 - 1) accounts
    from 
        cte
        cross apply (select charindex('#', accounts) ind1) ca
        cross apply (select charindex('#', accounts, ind1 + 1) ind2) cb
    union all
    select
        company, stuff(acc, ind1, ind2 - ind1, ''), substring(acc, ind1 + 1, ind2 - ind1 - 1)
    from
        rcte
        cross apply (select charindex('#', acc) ind1) ca
        cross apply (select charindex('#', acc, ind1 + 1) ind2) cb
    where
        len(acc)>1
) ,cte2 as (

    select company, accounts as  accounts_raw, Replace( accounts,'..','') as accounts,
        LEAD(accounts) OVER(Partition by company ORDER BY accounts) ld,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY accounts) rn 
    from rcte
) , cte3 as (

    Select company,accounts,ld ,rn 
    from cte2 
    WHERE ld not like '%..' 
) , cte4 as (
    select * from cte3 where accounts not in (select ld from cte3 t1 where t1.rn < cte3.rn)
)

SELECT company,accounts,ld from cte4
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT company,ld,NULL from cte3 where accounts not in (select accounts from cte4 t1)

option (maxrecursion 0)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that list (#6005..#6010) is represented like #6005#6006#6007#6008#6009#6010 in your Excel file. Try this query if that is true and there are no gaps

```
with cte as (
select 
    company, replace(replace(replace(accounts,'(',''),')',''),'+','')+'#' accounts
from 
    (values ('company 1','#3000#3001#3002#3003'),('company 2','(#4000#4001)+(#4021#4022)'),('company 3','(#5000#5001)+#6000+(#6005#6006)')) data(company, accounts)
)

, rcte as (
    select 
        company, stuff(accounts, ind1, ind2 - ind1, '') acc, substring(accounts, ind1 + 1, ind2 - ind1 - 1) accounts
    from 
        cte
        cross apply (select charindex('#', accounts) ind1) ca
        cross apply (select charindex('#', accounts, ind1 + 1) ind2) cb
    union all
    select
        company, stuff(acc, ind1, ind2 - ind1, ''), substring(acc, ind1 + 1, ind2 - ind1 - 1)
    from
        rcte
        cross apply (select charindex('#', acc) ind1) ca
        cross apply (select charindex('#', acc, ind1 + 1) ind2) cb
    where
        len(acc)>1
)

select
    company, min(accounts) FirstAcc, case when max(accounts)  =min(accounts) then null else max(accounts) end LastAcc
from (
    select
        company, accounts, accounts - row_number() over (partition by company order by accounts) group_
    from 
        rcte
    ) t
group by company, group_

option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you tagged SSIS so I will provide a solution for that using a script task. All other examples require loading to a staging table.

1. Use your normal reader (Excel  probably) and load
2. Add a script transformation component
3. Edit Component
4. Input Columns - Check both Company and Accounts
5. Input and Output - Add a new Output and call it CompFirstLast
6. Add three columns to it - Company string, First int, and Last int
7. Open Script and paste the following code

   ```
   public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
   {

   //Create an array for each group to create rows out of by splitting on '+'

   string[] SplitForRows = Row.Accounts.Split('+'); //Note single quotes denoting char 

   //Deal with each group and create the new Output
   for (int i = 0; i < SplitForRows.Length; i++) //Loop each split column
       {
           CompFirstLastBuffer.AddRow();
           CompFirstLastBuffer.Company = Row.Company; //This is static for each incoming row

           //Clean up the string getting rid of (). and leaving a delimited list of #
           string accts = SplitForRows[i].Replace("(", String.Empty).Replace(")", String.Empty).Replace(".", String.Empty).Substring(1);

           //Split into Array
           string[] accounts = accts.Split('#');

           // Write out first and last and handle null
           CompFirstLastBuffer.First = int.Parse(accounts[0]);

           if (accounts.Length == 1)
               CompFirstLastBuffer.Last_IsNull = true;
           else
               CompFirstLastBuffer.Last = int.Parse(accounts[1]);

       }
   }
   ```
8. Make sure you use the right output.

Comment: If your list is more like uzi said (#3001#3002#3003)+ then change the very last line CompFirstLastBuffer.Last = int.Parse(accounts[1]); to CompFirstLastBuffer.Last = int.Parse(accounts[accounts.length-1]);

Comment: Also, instead of returning null for only 1 value, you might want to set both to accounts[0] giving a start and end of same value. I am assuming you will be doing some between logic in the future.

Comment: @Hadi... thanks for cleaning it up. i couldn't figure out how to get it all to look like code

Comment: the first line after enumeration needed some additional space to be formated like code. Ur welcome :)